# chatroom message diffrent background color between sender and reciever doesnt work

Tags: php

What i want to do is make the message will have diffrent background color between sender and reciever

here is my code

```
<?php 

  include '../config.php';
  include'login.php';

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];

  $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

  $sql = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO logs(`username`, `msg`)VALUES('$username', '$msg')");
  $sql1= "SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id ASC ";

  $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);

  if ($_SESSION['username'] == $username)
    $color = 'red';
  else
    $color = 'purple';

  while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){

  echo "
  <div class='left-wrap-message' style='background-color:$color;'>
    <span class = 'username'>". $extract['username']. 
    "</span><span class='msg'> : "  . $extract['msg']. "</span></div><br>";
    }

?>
```

here is the logs file for load the message out

```
<?php 
  include '../config.php';
  include'login.php';

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];

  $sql1= "SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id ASC";

  $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);


 if ($_SESSION['username'] == $username)
    $color = 'red';
 else
    $color = 'purple';


 while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){

 echo "<div class='left-wrap-message' style='background-color:$color;'>
 <span  class = 'username'>". $extract['username']. "</span>
 <span  class='msg'> : " . $extract['msg']. "</span></div><br>";
 }
```

?>

Anything i mess out? i dk why it wont work

Comment: error checking said what exactly?

Comment: no error ~~ all background color are red it cant check which are sender and reciever

Comment: You need to check username **inside** the message loop, not outside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the $username with the extract username in the loop ,this should work :

**PHP**

```
  <?php 

  include '../config.php';
  include'login.php';

  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

  $sql = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO logs(`username`, `msg`)VALUES('$username', '$msg')");
  $sql1= "SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id ASC ";

  $result1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);

  while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
  $color = ($extract['username'] == $username) ? 'red' : 'purple';
  $position = ($extract['username'] == $username) ? 'left' : 'right';
  echo "
  <div class='" . $position . "-wrap-message' style='background-color:$color;'>
    <span class = 'username'>". $extract['username']. 
    "</span><span class='msg'> : "  . $extract['msg']. "</span></div><br>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: WOW THX its work! but if i want it left and right how to i do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're setting `$username = $_SESSION['username'];`, so when it gets to your if/else statement, it's always going to resolve as true.

You need to put your if/else inside the while, and compare the row username to $username.