# if statement that changes color of div if the div value = session username

Tags: php, html, css, session, mysqli

I'm trying things our for a messaging system I'm creating. I'm attempting to use an if statement to change the color of the name of the person who's sending the message, if you are the person sending it. So for example if i receive a message from a user, his name will come up in black, and if i send him a message back, my name will come up in red.

In short, change the color of div#sender to red if the $_SESSION['userName'] is the person sending the message.

```
$user = $_SESSION['userName'];
        $qu = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `to`='$user' OR `from`='$user'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($qu) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qu)) {
        echo '<tr><td><div id="sender">'.$row["from"].'</div></td><td><div id="r_message">'.$row["message"].'</div></td></tr>';

            }
        }

if(''.$row["from"].'' == $user){

echo'

<style>

#sender{
color:red;

}

</style>

';

}
else{echo'NO';}
```

I'm getting my echoed "NO", every time, even though plenty of the messages in the database are sent by the $_SESSION user, as well as other users.

Comment: Start with `var_Dump($row["from"], $user);` Also, do you understand that you compare after your `while` loop is over?

Comment: ..and if that ^ shows as `null`, then your code failed.

Comment: It certainly looks to *me* that your logic ought to be __inside__ that while-loop.  If, say, you want certain `<tr>`s to be highlighted in certain ways, the easiest way to do this is to create a CSS Style for each one.  Then, in your loop (and before you generate any output), you decide which style you want to specify in the `<tr>` tag when you proceed to generate it.

Comment: I swear, I've seen this question before. Oh yeah.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37325588/chatroom-message-diffrent-background-color-between-sender-and-reciever-doesnt-wo/37325746#37325746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$row` array is created in the loop and you're using outside of the loop. Also, you're creating multiple duplicate ID's this way. You should use classes.

try something like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qu)) {
    if($row['from']==$user) $class='sender';
    else $class = 'reciever';
    echo '<tr><td><div class="'.$class.'">'.$row["from"].'</div></td><td><div id="r_message">'.$row["message"].'</div></td></tr>';
}
```

and then just put this in the headder, no need to output it with PHP..

```
<style>
.sender{ color: red; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks man, simple and easy. Looked completely over the "inside the while loop thing. This did exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do...

First, in the CSS stylesheet for the page, define two style-classes for a `<tr>`.  Let's call 'em `good_guy` and `bad_guy`.  *(Why not?*)

Now, in that loop, you simply decide which style you want to use:

```
    $qu = mysqli_query($con, 
       "SELECT * FROM `messages` "
       . "WHERE `to`='$user' OR `from`='$user'"
    );
    if (mysqli_num_rows($qu) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qu)) {

        $class = ( $row["from"] == 'Brutus' : 'bad_guy' : 'good_guy' );

    echo "<tr class='$class'>"   // note use of double-quotes here!
       .   "<td>"
       .     "<div id='sender'>".$row["from"]."</div>";
       .   "</td>"
 ... blah blah blah blah blah ...
       . "</tr>";

    }  // end while
 } // end if
```

Now, you'll immediately notice how I *also* tried to expand things out to make them more readable.  *(I hope I didn't make any syntax errors or mispeluns.)*

As noted, the use of *double* quotes is necessary to cause PHP to *interpolate* the variable `$class` when it occurs within the literal text of the string.

Brutus is gonna get flagged as a bad-guy when (Caesar) looks at this page.  All of the visual particulars of how a `good_guy` or a `bad_guy` looks are resolved in the CSS stylesheet.  (In my opinion, you should always use named styles from a sheet, not in-line style tags.)

Comment: dude is clearly a noob and probably needs the ternary explained as well, also, you're still creating multiple instances of elements with the same ID, other than that, this is basically the same as my answer, but +1 for humor..

Comment: he's got a typo, should be changed to `$class = ( $row["from"] == 'Brutus' ? 'bad_guy' : 'good_guy' );` (the first colon should be a question mark.

Comment: but even then `$class` would always evaluate to 'good_guy' because 'Brutus' is hardcoded and will never evaluate to false/